# vim can't recognize Podfile and podspec file as Ruby file

Tags: ruby, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting, podfile

How to make vim recognize Podfile and podspec file (some file without extension) as ruby file, so that vim can make syntax highlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your *.vimrc*:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead Podfile,*.podspec set filetype=ruby
```

This line instructs Vim to treat *Podfiles* and files with a *.podspec* extension as Ruby files so they inherit the Ruby syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

For NeoVim / Lua:

```lua
local auto_command_on = vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd

auto_command_on({ "BufRead", "BufNewFile" }, {
  pattern = { "*.podspec", "Podfile" },
  command = "set filetype=ruby",
})
```

when you open/create a '.podspec' or 'Podfile', neovim treat the file as a ruby one

*based on **Cy Rossignol** answer.*